# Help identifying protocol for Midea AC daughter PCB communication

Tags: protocol, logic-analyzer

I have a basic Midea AC unit that lacks Wi-Fi connectivity, and I'm interested in making it smart. It consists of a main PCB, which I prefer not to tamper with, and a smaller daughter PCB responsible for receiving remote control inputs and communicating with the main PCB via four wires. The daughter PCB features a SinoWealth chip (SH79F1612A) (https://en.sinowealth.com/seach?search=sh79f1612a).

I managed to intercept and analyze the signals on the four wires using a logic analyzer, but I'm struggling to identify the protocol being utilized.

Despite thorough research, I remain at an impasse.

[image]

It repeats every 270ms.

Here is the Logic session: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QbaE9Mh5UVACoj3hOT8B4BaaSTL8iYrq/view?usp=drive_link

Comment: Post a picture from the screen. We cannot guess what program or what version and on which OS to run it to open that file. Also be extremely careful as the logic supply is internal so it might not be isolated from mains but practically be considered live.

Comment: I added a picture from the screen. I used Saleae Logic 2 on win11. I measured before messing with anything, the logic is 5v.